# include $page; NOT working

Tags: php

Hi
I have included this in my index.php

```
include $page;
```

but it is not working on live server BUT WORKING FINE on my Localhost.
I have also included `include ('includes/_ini.php');` on the top of index.php page in which `$page` is defined.
Please suggest

On server it giving the following WARNING

```
Warning: include(?pgid=1&parid=&rid=1&lang=1) [function.include]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /opt/lampp/htdocs/mysite.com/index.php on line 290

Warning: include(?pgid=1&parid=&rid=1&lang=1) [function.include]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /opt/lampp/htdocs/mysite.com/index.php on line 290

Warning: include() [function.include]: Failed opening '?pgid=1&parid=&rid=1&lang=1' for inclusion (include_path='.:/opt/lampp/lib/php') in /opt/lampp/htdocs/mysite.com/index.php on line 290
```

Comment: set to display error reporting and see what it says. You could be mislinking the files

Comment: that code is dangerous. dont use variables on include commands. you may get security problems with hat! remote file inclusions or they can view your secret files!

Comment: This is a major disaster waiting to happen. Guess what will happen when URL wrappers are enabled and someone passes `?page=http://domain.com/script.txt` to your script (where script.txt is a file containing some PHP code).

Comment: what is the best way to do this..pls suggest

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `include()` statement includes and evaluates the `**specified file**`.

**Look at your warning:**

```
Warning: include(?pgid=1&parid=&rid=1&lang=1)
```

Compare to this (your code)

```
include $page;
```

So =>

```
   $page = ?pgid=1&parid=&rid=1&lang=1
```

`**specified file**` not like your format here: `?pgid=1&parid=&rid=1&lang=1` (it is just the URL not the path of existing file)

for example:

```
/* This example assumes that www.example.com is configured to parse .php
* files and not .txt files. Also, 'Works' here means that the variables
* $foo and $bar are available within the included file. */

// Won't work; file.txt wasn't handled by www.example.com as PHP
include 'http://www.example.com/file.txt?foo=1&bar=2';

// Won't work; looks for a file named 'file.php?foo=1&bar=2' on the
// local filesystem.
include 'file.php?foo=1&bar=2';

// Works.
include 'http://www.example.com/file.php?foo=1&bar=2';

$foo = 1;
$bar = 2;
include 'file.txt';  // Works.
include 'file.php';  // Works.
```

More take a look here:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php

Answer (score 4):

The warning is clear; `$page` contains `?pgid=1&parid=&rid=1&lang=1` which is not a valid file name to include. A valid file name would be for example `foo/bar.php`.

Comment: yes it is the valid name..see how--www.mysite.com/?pgid=1&parid=&rid=1&lang=1

Answer (score 2):

It seems `$page` is in url format. Its not the path of file.

You must use `path of file to include`.

file name must be as

`folder/file1.php`  for `linux` (use /)

and

`folder\file1.php`  for `windows` (use )